# move the custom scroll by using mouse scrolling event in jQuery Custom Scrollbar

Tags: jquery

I am using this https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar/ plugin for custom scroll bar. Its working fine in all the browsers.

The problem is, I want to move the horizontal scroll bar by using mouse scroll event. Any one can help? please!

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Scrollbar</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.custom-scrollbar.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*Horizontal scrollbar - set width and height of a div you want to add a scrollbar to*/
        #horizontal-scrollbar-demo {
            width: 98%;
            height: 200px;
        }
        /*Horizontal scrollbar - set width of overview or make it expand horizontal like below*/
        #horizontal-scrollbar-demo .overview {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        #horizontal-scrollbar-demo img {
            height: 180px;
            width: auto;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="jquery.custom-scrollbar.js"></script>          
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".demo").customScrollbar();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Horizontal scrollbar</h2>
    <div id="horizontal-scrollbar-demo" class="modern-skin demo">
        <img src="images/OOH_Horizontal-A_Page_2_3.jpg" style="padding-right:10px;"/>
        <img src="images/OOH_Horizontal-A_Page_3_1_3.jpg" style="padding-right:10px;"/>
        <img src="images/OOH_Horizontal-A_Page_4_3.jpg" style="padding-right:10px;"/>
        <img src="images/OOH_Horizontal-A_Page_7_3.jpg" style="padding-right:10px;"/>
        <img src="images/TomAndJenny_Gap_3.jpg" style="padding-right:10px;"/>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want some smooth scroll effect like, http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ (mcustomscrollbar).

Comment: Do you want to programmatically scroll by calling [`.scollToX(x)`](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar/#scrolltoxx)? Most (maybe all modern) browsers perform horizontal scrolling using the mouse wheel if the *shift* key is also pressed.

Comment: for resize, its having the option updateOnWindowResize:true like that, is there any option for mousescroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be an option to configure this in the library. But assuming that your container has *no vertical scrollbar* you could <strike>extend</strike> hack the plugin by altering the order in which the mouse wheel delta is supplied to the various functions.

In the [source](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar/blob/master/jquery.custom-scrollbar.js#L628), you could change

```
args.unshift(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);
```

to

```
args.unshift(event, delta, deltaY, deltaX);
```

You could also create an issue on github asking for this functionality to be added, or make a pull request yourself :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply andyb,But still i'm getting the same issue.

Comment: I have tested this locally and it is working for me. Does your container _only_ have a horizontal scrollbar? Do you have a demo in which I can see the problem?

Comment: thanks! Its working for me. Thank you very much. Also can we increase the scroll speed while we are clicking and scrolling? Now its moving page by page in horizontally.

Comment: Do you mean something like holding left button and scroll together?

Comment: like smooth scroll, now its effect is jumping, want to move with smoothly. Can we do that?

Comment: It's not jumping for me in my local demo but I don't have access to all of your code. Also, this feels like a new question to me. I recommend asking a new question but link to this question to give people some background information. It will also get more views than a question that has already been answered. I expect that I am the only one watching this question at the moment! I would also try to provide some demo code in your new question.

Comment: If you give that it will be a great help to me. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, you have now totally changed the question! Are you using a different plugin now? It looks like the second plugin also works horizontally. I strongly recommend asking a new question if you are using a different plugin now.

Comment: No, I'm using the same plugin